# Getting Error when trying to install synaptic in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I am new to linux and installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit on my machine. I was attempting to install "synaptic" and used this command:

```
sudo apt-get install 

synaptic Reading package lists... Done Building
dependency tree        Reading state information... Done The following
additional packages will be installed:   docbook-xml libcairo-perl
libept1.5.0 libglib-perl libgtk2-perl libpango-perl   librarian0
rarian-compat sgml-data Suggested packages:   docbook docbook-dsssl
docbook-xsl docbook-defguide libfont-freetype-perl   libgtk2-perl-doc
perlsgml w3-recs opensp libxml2-utils dwww menu deborphan  
apt-xapian-index tasksel The following NEW packages will be installed:
docbook-xml libcairo-perl libept1.5.0 libglib-perl libgtk2-perl
libpango-perl   librarian0 rarian-compat sgml-data synaptic 0
upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 135 not upgraded. Need
to get 0 B/2,888 kB of archives. After this operation, 16.4 MB of
additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: error: configuration error:
/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/architectures:1: unknown option
'foreign-architecture' E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error
code (2)
```

I have seen some other solutions here, but seems not working in my case. Don't know how to solve or how do i install synaptic. Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance.